# Null origin CSRF in HTTP POST, is it possible?

Tags: csrf

Is it possible to construct an HTTP POST based CSRF attack with a null origin?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by loading a data URL:

```
data:text/html,<form method="POST" action="https://demo.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/origin.php"><input type="submit"></form>
```

This can also be loaded within an iframe on a normal page.

Or when the request is done to one origin, and it redirects to another origin.

A number of cases are described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin#description) and you can try it out [here](https://demo.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/origin.php).